# What is the equivalence of Edit Sequence in QuickBooks POS?

Tags: quickbooks, point-of-sale, qbxml

Does anyone know what is the equivalence of EditSequence (in Quickbooks) for QuickBooks Point Of Sale?

Apparently I found, there is none.

Comment: Are you using QB IntuitAnywhere API ? In that case, most probably you are referring 'syncToken' which tracks edit/mod sequences.
For ex - check the response xml of customer create request.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/customer#Sample_Create_Response_XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an editsequence in POS.